# how can I call function every 10 sec?

Tags: android, android-handler

I want make an app that call a function for example every 10 sec.

I wrote my code like this:

```
Handler ha=new Handler();
ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call function

    }
}, 10000);
```

But my function call just one time in 10 sec after compile this code.

How can I fix it?

Comment: user timer and schedual them

Comment: add ha.postDelayed(this, 10000); at the end of run

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
final Handler ha=new Handler();
ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call function

        ha.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: your way take very much ram & can be slow device

Comment: how can we implement same thing with the Timer ?

Answer (score 9):

Use a combination of `Timer` and `TimerTask` like this:

```
int delay = 0; // delay for 0 sec. 
int period = 10000; // repeat every 10 sec. 
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        //Call function
    } 
}, delay, period);
```

Also make sure to use `runOnUiThread()` if you want to modify the UI.

Comment: I do it.but my app call function one time & then my app hang & force close.  how can I fix it?

Comment: Hard to tell without your LogCat.

Comment: You might be modifying the UI and not using `runOnUiThread()` as mentioned earlier by FD_

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Rx java** & **Rx Android** by adding this dependency as below :

```
//Rx Java
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.13'

//Rx Android
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

checkout [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) for the latest version.

You need an Observable like this :

```
private final Observable etaUpdateRepeatableObservable =
        Observable
                .interval(ETA_UPDATE_INTERVALS, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeat();
```

just change `ETA_UPDATE_INTERVALS` to your specific value.

You need a **Disposable** for subscribing to observable and to **dispose** it when required (Like **onCleared()** on **ViewModels**)

```
private Disposable etaUpdateDisposable;
```

You need a **Consumer** that your repeated logic would go there.

```
private final Consumer etaUpdateConsumer = o -> {
    //Here you got the repeated logic
};
```

Now you can **subscribe**(Start repeating function) and **dispose**(stop)  **observable** every time you need.

```
  private void addEtaUpdateDisposable() {
    if (etaUpdateDisposable == null) {
        etaUpdateDisposable = etaUpdateRepeatableObservable.subscribe(etaUpdateConsumer);
    }
}

private void disposeEtaUpdate() {
    if (
            etaUpdateDisposable != null &&
                    !etaUpdateDisposable.isDisposed()
    ) {
        etaUpdateDisposable.dispose();
        etaUpdateDisposable = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks that Timer and TimerTask are what are you looking for

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
     public void run() {
         //your code
     });
}
    };

timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 10000);
```

Comment: I do it.but my app call function one time & then my app hang & force close. how can I fix it?

Comment: you have to give us more details. it is hard to know why your app is hanging without code...

Comment: i am using timer Task and also handler but handler and timer task continue going so after 10 to 15 minuet whole app and phone is hang and freeze is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Create Handler object before TimerTask and then use that handler object inside run() method. handler.post(new Runnable() { public void run(){ Update UI } );

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //your function
                }
            }, 10000);
```

Comment: I do it.but my app call function one time & then my app hang & force close. how can I fix it?

Comment: Create Handler object and then use it inside run() method to update UI.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of alternative ways to do this. Personally, I prefer to use ScheduledExecutorService: